# Installing scoped npm packages from Artifactory

Tags: node.js, apache, tomcat, npm, artifactory

I am trying to get scoped npm packages to work with Artifactory behind Apache.  I can publish a scoped package to Artifactory and it creates the following path in the npm-local repo: `@scopename/packagename/-/@scopename/packagename-version.tgz`

My problems arise trying to install this package.  I get a `404 Not Found: @scopename/packagename`.  Looking at the debug log I can see that maybe it has something to do with the encoding of the slashes:

```
22 http request GET https://artifacts.company.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-local/@scopename%2fpackagename
23 http 404 https://artifacts.company.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-local/@scopename%2fpackagename
```

I have followed the online documentation. I added `AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode` to the virtual host and `org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true` to the catalina.properties file on tomcat.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a reverse proxy issue. Check your `request.log`. If the request is coming is as `/api/npm/npm-group/@angular/core` instead of `/api/npm/npm-group/@angular%2Fcore`, that is something that need to addressed in your reverse proxy.

You have to change two things:

1. Implement the setting `org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH = true`
2. Remove of the context root from the `proxy_pass` variable in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

Comment: thank you for the response, I am using apache not nginx.  Are you saying that it should come back with a "/" or a "%2F" ?

Comment: It should come back as a "/"

Even if you're not using Nginx, see if there's a similar setting in Apache. You may be running artifactory off Apache, but I believe Artifactory also by default uses Nginx as a reverse proxy. If Apache is handling both, then check and see if there is a similar setting.

Comment: it should look like %2F all the way