# how can i get scoped npm packages form artifactory

Tags: npm, artifactory

I have a problem with pulling scoped packages from artifactory remote repository

I have watched item : [[Installing scoped npm packages from Artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40870241/installing-scoped-npm-packages-from-artifactory][1])

my virtual repository name is `swm-virtual-npm`

I did a :

```
npm config set registry http://server:8080/artifactory/swm-virtual-npm

npm install @angular/core
```

and it fails. when I do it with gulp package it works.

I have added the `org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH = true` flag.

the data the request.log gives me is :

> 20170329113552|12|REQUEST|10.82.72.231|anonymous|GET|/swm-virtual-npm/@angular%2fcore|HTTP/1.1|302|0 20170329113552|0|REQUEST|10.82.72.231|anonymous|GET|/ui/nativeBrowser|HTTP/1.1|406|0 20170329113552|1|REQUEST|10.82.72.231|anonymous|GET|/swm-virtual-npm/@angular%2fcore/|HTTP/1.1|406|0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is quite simple, you are missing the [required api/npm](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry#NpmRegistry-UsingtheNpmCommandLine) in the URL. It should be:

npm config set registry http://server:8080/artifactory/api/npm/swm-virtual-npm

Your ~/.npmrc should look something like this:

```
registry=http://server:8080/artifactory/api/npm/swm-virtual-npm
_auth = ......
always-auth = true
```

You may want to delete all the content in your NPM remote repository caches (if there are any in what I assume is a virtual NPM repository). It is likely your attempts to access it without **api/npm** may have corrupted the cache.

Comment: first of all it worked. I tried before the api/npm syntax but did not delete the content in my remote repository. after deleting the contenet in the remote repository it worked. thanks