# Publish scoped npm package to Artifactory Online

Tags: npm, artifactory

I'm trying to publish a scoped npm package to Artifactory Online: my-company.jfrog.io/my-company

I'm experiencing the same problem described in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40870241/installing-scoped-npm-packages-from-artifactory) where I publish my package `@scope/my-package` and it deploys to Artifactory just fine but it winds up in the Artifactory Online path: `npm-internal/@scope/my-package/-/@scope/my-package-1.2.3.tgz`

When I run `npm view @scope/my-package` I get the 404 error:

`npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @scope/my-package`

In Artifactory, packages can be moved, and so I tried moving it from:

`npm-internal/@scope/my-package/-/@scope/my-package-1.2.3.tgz`

to

`npm-internal/@scope/my-package-1.2.3.tgz`

and try `npm view @scope/my-package`, get package details, and can perform an `npm install @scope/my-package` to install it.

Every answer I've found online has a solution to configure Tomcat to AllowEncodedSlashed.  Is there an Artifactory Online equivalent?

I've rummaged through as much of the web app as I can think to rummage through to find anything resembling a configuration option to allow this to work and found nothing.  I haven't found anything searching the docs.

Answer (score 1):

According to [artifactory docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry#NpmRegistry-DeployingYourPackages):

> There are two ways to deploy packages to a local repository:
>
> - Edit your package.json file and add a publishConfig section to a local repository:
>     "publishConfig":{"registry":"http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npm-local/"}
> - Provide a local repository to the npm publish command:
>     npm publish --registry http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npm-local/

You can [deploy a packed npm package to a specific path in your registry](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry#NpmRegistry-RepositoryLayout).  Given this, the following can be performed:

```
npm run build
npm pack dist/
npm publish scope-my-package-1.2.3.tgz --registry https://my-company.jfrog.io/my-company/api/npm/internal-npm/@scope/my-package/
npm view @scope/my-package
```

And this works.  The newly deployed package can be viewed now.